# php unset array element while keeping numbers in order

Tags: php, arrays

I apologize in advance for this question - I'm sure it's been answered before, (hell, *I've* done it before), I just can't find anything in the search and my brain is drawing a blank...

I have an array in PHP where `print_r` outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => VALUE
    [1] => VALUE
    [2] => VALUE
    [3] => VALUE
    [4] => VALUE
)
```

I use `unset($_SESSION['item'][$lineID]);` to unset a particular line from the array, and I'm left with:

```
Array
(
    [0] => VALUE
    [1] => VALUE
    [3] => VALUE
    [4] => VALUE
)
```

Element `[2]` has been removed, so the resulting array is no longer numerically in order

(e.g. - `[0][1][3][4]` instead of `[0][1][2][3]` ).

What PHP command do I run on the resulting array to "take out blanks" and reformat it so that it is numerically in order from *1 to n*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To reset array keys after `unset()`

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

Comment: freaking `array_values`..... that's it.  /monday.

Comment: I recommend using `array_splice` instead of unset, which eliminates the use of `array_values`